# Proxying requests from React to External REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm working on a website made with React, run with `npm`. The website currently uses a JS API run with the website code, but we're migrating to using an external REST API. Everything's configured correctly to run locally with a webpack dev server:

```
proxy: {
    '/apiv1': 'http://localhost:5000/', // in prod, run in the same container
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/', // in prod, run separately on a different url (api.website.com)
        pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' },
    },
},
```

In the console, I see errors complaining that some data is undefined (using the minified variable names, so difficult to track down--but almost certainly data from the API).

I checked if it was a CORS issue per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495976/django-and-react-error-message-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app), but I'm still having the same issue with CORS disabled completely.

I can successfully ping the api with a direct request, placed at the beginning of the base App's render method:

```js
axios.get("https://api.website.com/")
```

I've tried to add the following to my `package.json` per [this](https://dev.to/codewithbernard/solved-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-41kp):

```json
"homepage": ".",
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://api.website.com",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
```

In general -- how can I proxy requests for `website.com/api/request` to `api.website.com/request` in production? Is there something else I'm configuring incorrectly?

Please let me know if there's any more information I can add!

Edit:
I've also tried configuring the proxy with `http-proxy-middleware`:

```js
// src/setupProxy.js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: "https://api.website.com",
            pathRewrite: {
                "^/api": ""
            },
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Likely you are not serving js files

Comment: @antokhio Nothing has been changed about the way the JS is served since the current version, which works fine. The only change is the addition of the external API and associated proxy.

Comment: I'm actually fairly sure the "need to enable JavaScript" was entirely a red herring and has nothing to do with the actual issue. It was showing up on API requests because it was failing to redirect the request to the API, and as such was trying to render the website instead in the web inspector preview.

Comment: Well there is few stuff that might break, so idk, what's on your Chrome network tab, the proposed debugging way is to make sure first that your actually getting data in browser...

Comment: The network tab shows 200 responses for all API requests, but the actual response content is just the bundled js of the frontend (not the json I expect). Like I said, a direct request e.g. `axios.get("api.website.com/data")` works fine, but the proxied `axios.get("/api/data")` doesn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

[Proxying api requests in production for React/Express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955965/proxying-api-requests-in-production-for-react-express-app)

> In production we can't use (proxy).. instead we can set a variable in the frontend for the backend URL, and vise versa.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096

> proxy is just that: a development feature. It is not meant for production.

These suggest that it's entirely impossible. Makes sense that the proxy option won't work, but I can't say I understand why there's no equivalent functionality for a production environment. It seems the best option for me is making all calls to the full domain instead of proxying.

If you're using nginx, the linked answers suggest using that to proxy the requests:

```
upstream backend-server {
  server api.example.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/build;
  index index.html;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend-server;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```